# Fill vuetify combobox with data from function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetiy combobox that's part of a form in which the user can search voor data by email and it returns a object (a visitor):

```
 <EmailInput
   v-model="selectedVisitor"
   :required="true"
   :autocomplete="true"
   :items="visitors"
  />
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field
    v-if="!autocomplete"
      :rules="[
        (v) => !!v || $t('error.emailRequired'),
        (v) => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || $t('error.emailInvalid'),
      ]"
      outlined
      :label="label"
      required
      @input="$emit('input', $event)"
    />

    <v-combobox
      v-if="autocomplete"
      :rules="[
        (v) => !!v || $t('error.emailRequired'),
      ]"
      :label="label"
      outlined
      append-icon="arrow_drop_down"
      :items="items"
      item-text="email"
      item-value="email"
      @input="$emit('input', $event)"
    >
      <template v-slot:selection="data">
        {{ data.item.email || data.item }}
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item="data">
        {{ data.item.name }} - {{ data.item.email }}
      </template>
    </v-combobox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    required: Boolean,
    items: Array,
    autocomplete: Boolean,
  },
  computed: {
    label() {
      if (this.required === true) {
        return this.$i18n.t('labels.emailReq');
      }
      return this.$i18n.t('labels.email');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

If an existing visitor is found, the other form fields are filled, otherwise just the email is sent to the `newVisitor` object.

```
    selectedVisitor(val) {
      if (typeof val === 'object' && val !== null) {
        this.newAppointment.visitorId = val.id;
        this.existingVisitor = true; // we don't have to write it to the db
        Object.assign(this.newVisitor, val); // for displaying the data only, object assign because db array was edited too when data was modified or deleted
      } else if (val === null || val === '') {
        this.newAppointment.visitorId = '';
        this.newVisitor = {};
      } else {
        this.newVisitor.email = val;
      }
    },
```

The user then clicks a button and the data gets sent to the `multipleVisitors` array.

The problem is with the function that repopulates these form fields if the user wants to edit the data:

```
 editVisitor(email) {
   // get the visitor that needs to be edited
   const visitorArray = this.multipleVisitors.filter((el) => el.email === email);
   const visitor = visitorArray[0];
   // set the visitor to the form
   this.newVisitor = visitor;
   // variable set to combobox
   this.selectedVisitor = visitor.email;

   // remove the visitor from the visitor array
   this.multipleVisitors = this.multipleVisitors.filter((el) => el.email !== email);
 },
```

The form is filled in except for the combobox which stays empty. If I look at vue dev tools the variable assigned to the v-model does contain the email address.

I've tried assigning the whole object to `selectedVisitor` but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

this could maybe help

```html
<v-combobox :items="MyFillFuntion()"></v-combobox>
```

```html
<v-combobox :items="MyFillFuntion(scopeData)" # optional></v-combobox>
```

and don't forget

```js
<script>
export default {
 data: () => ({
   MyFillFuntion() {
     let array_i_need_to_fill = [];

     //  your process ...  ...

     // and finally
     return  array_i_need_to_fill;
   }
 }),
  props: {
    required: Boolean,
    items: Array,
    autocomplete: Boolean,
  },
  computed: {
    label() {
      if (this.required === true) {
        return this.$i18n.t('labels.emailReq');
      }
      return this.$i18n.t('labels.email');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```